# How to modify bootstrap 4 with sass without editing bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using bootstrap CDN and I need to override bootstrap with sass by creating new css for modified codes.

for eg: I have two bootstrap css, one is bootstrapcdn and another one is modified by sass (main.css). main.css also included bootstrap default classes and new/override classes created by sass. I need to save override/new classes as separate css file. How can I save override classes as new css by using sass?.

like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/bootstrap-cdn.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/modified.css">
```

I have added new color variable named `$tertiary` like `$primary` and this is adding or modifying the bootstrap classes like

```
:root { --tertiary: #66F;} 
.list-group-item-tertiary {} 
.btn-outline-tertiary {}
```

I need to save this updated codes in to new css.

below is my files and it's structure if needed

```
|-- \bootstrap-scss
|   |   |-- \mixins
|   |   |-- \utilities
|   |   |-- variables.scss
|   |   |-- functions.scss
|   |   |-- ...more bootstrap scss files
|-- \custom-scss
|   |   |-- _custom.scss
|   |   |-- _variable.scss
|   |   |-- main.scss
```

_variables.scss

```
    $tertiary:          #66F;
    $theme-colors: () !default;
    $theme-colors: map-merge(
      (
        "tertiary":    $tertiary),
      $theme-colors
    );
```

main.scss

```
@import "variables";
// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../bootstrap-scss/functions";
@import "../bootstrap-scss/variables";
@import "../bootstrap-scss/mixins";
// Optional
@import "../bootstrap-scss/ all scss files ";
@import "custom";
```

Comment: I'm not getting your question, are you getting css output you was looking for? the question is "how to save it"?

Comment: Ok,  I have two bootstrap css, one is bootstrapcdn and another one is modified by sass (main.css). 
main.css also included bootstrap default classes and new/override classes created by sass. I need to save override/new classes as separate css file. How can I save override classes as new css by using sass?.

Comment: which scss compiler do you use now?
e.g. if you use regular scss CLI compiler then the css path is specified there `scss --watch assets/scss:assets/css --style=compressed`. this command watches for changes in `/assets/scss` folder and saves minified css into `/assets/css` folder from where you include your css afterwards
note you need ruby and scss installed for that http://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: I am using sass and it's working perfect, there is no issue with compile or override the files. 
the problem is the compiled css also included all the default classes + added/updated classes.  
I don't want the bootstrap default classes in the new compiled css because I already included bootstrap cdn. I need only the updated/added classes in the compiled css.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file with the preferred styles is selected last. You can also add '!Important' to the preferred classes, particularly if you need to override.